# How to pipe part of the output matching pattern into the file, leaving the rest to stdout?

Tags: bash, grep, tee

Let `a.out` be the program which produces lots of messages to stdout, e.g.:

```
$ ./a.out

A: abc
B: xyz
A: aaa
A: bbb
B: zzz
C: fff
...
```

What I need is to distinct the output into separate files, one should contain lines with `A:` prefix, second with `B:` and so all, leaving the lines which does not match any pattern to stdout.

Of course one can redirect the whole output of `a.out`, and then `grep`ing it. But if output file will use much disk space, there may be not enough space for `grep` result.

It would be nice to have some `partial-redirect` command which can be used in that case like that:

```
./a.out | partial-redirect ^A: a.txt | partial-redirect ^B: b.txt | partial-redirect ^C: c.txt > rest.txt
```

Is such command exist and common, or you should implement something yourself to solve this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F':' '$1 ~ "[AB]" { print > $1 } $1 !~ "[AB]" { print > "otheroutput" } ' input
```

Or, for a general case that will split the entire input based on the first field:

```
awk -F':' '{ print > $1 }' input
```

In use:

```
$ cat input
A: abc
B: xyz
A: aaa
A: bbb
B: zzz
C: fff
$ awk -F':' '$1 ~ "[AB]" { print > $1.txt } $1 !~ "[AB]" { print > "otheroutput" } ' input
$ cat A
A: abc
A: aaa
A: bbb
$ cat B
B: xyz
B: zzz
$ cat otheroutput
C: fff
```

Comment: It seems to fit only when the distinction criteria is line startings, correct me if I'm wrong. For example, if you want to redirect lines containing `logic error`, `network error`, etc., that approach won't work?

Comment: I went based on the provided example.  This approach would be adaptable to anything you can detect in `awk`.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that there is no tool for that and you have to implement something yourself. I don't think this example can be considered well-known scenario of awk usage.

Answer (score 1):

That's what `tee` is for in `bash`:

```
./a.out | tee >(grep A >fileA) | tee >(grep B >fileB) | grep C >fileC
```

or even simpler in `zsh`:

```
./a.out > >(grep A >fileA) > >(grep B >fileB) > >(grep C >fileC)
```

Comment: `tee` writes the whole stdin to stdout, I need to leave only lines that do not match pattern, so the second `grep` should be faster.